# Change cursor image on scrollbar in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I need to change custom cursor for scrollbar in Chrome. I have lightbox which has set custom cursor with big X and Close text. Problem is that in chrome the cursor definition is inherited by the scrollbar as well, which looks a bit funny.

See the fiddle:

```
<div class="below">
    <div class="full">
         <div class="scrollable">long text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.full{
    position:fixed;
    background:red;
    height:100%;
    width:80%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    cursor: url('cursor.cur'),not-allowed;
}
.scrollable{
    padding:1em;
    background:white;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:80%;
    margin:50px auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3fY9r/1/

is there any way how to trigger the scrollbar only and change the appearance back to default cursor?

Answer (score 17):

You can use the vendor selectors for chrome's scrollbar to set styles. However, I don't think it will allow you to change the cursor. You could try this to see if it works:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**UPDATE**

After looking more into this issue, apparently there is a bug with Chrome and updates to the cursor on scrollbars. Here is [the ticket](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=290466), it is still open. You can still change the styles, but the customizations seem a bit limited.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Seems like the story of this question pretty much ends here. I tried to apply the rule and what happened was that the scrollbar disappeared completely... http://jsfiddle.net/3fY9r/2/

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those edge-case things that they usually push off to fry bigger fish. You could always fake it by adding a div to the right side the same width as the scrollbar and set `cursor:pointer` on that!

Comment: @MatthewR. But if you placed a `div` over the scrollbar, wouldn't that prevent the use of the scrollbar?

Comment: @Spooky It might work if you use `pointer-events: none` on the `div`

Comment: @Pauan With `pointer-events: none`, "the element is never the target of mouse events".[\[src\]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) As a result, `cursor: pointer` will not be visible. Check my demo [here](http://jsbin.com/megogequpa/edit?output).

Comment: "due to this BUG fix of webkit, chrome will use the parent's cursor style for the child container." → https://stackoverflow.com/q/64402424/1066234

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `cursor: auto` to your scrollable class

```
.scrollable { 
  cursor: auto; 
}
```

Works with textareas, not sure with divs.