# webkit-scrollbar target a specific div

Tags: css

I am trying to hide scroll bar in chrome browser with following css style in my xyz.css file

> ::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;}

would this hide scroll bar in the whole application? I just want to target a specific div

something like

```
#mydiv.-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;}
```

how can i do this?

Comment: `#mydiv::-webkit-scrollbar{display:None;}`

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is as given with colon

```
#mydiv ::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;}
```

This will do it

Comment: #mydiv ::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;} there should be a space after #mydiv but thanx it worked.

Comment: @Ali If this answer worked, it would be great if you could mark it correct.

Comment: can you tell about compatibility with other browsers? My application will run on chrome only but asking just for knowledge.

Comment: `.myclass::-webkit-scrollbar` works, however, it does not work for to assigning a custom cursor to the scrollbar. → https://stackoverflow.com/a/23764846/1066234