# Highcharts: add cursor pointer to horizontal scroll

Tags: css, highcharts, scroll, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

How can I make cursor pointer style when the cursor hovers horizontal scrollbar at highcharts?

The demo is here: https://jsfiddle.net/greenfrontend/mxpb34ou/4/

I try to add:

`.highcharts-scrolling:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}`

but this doesn't help

Comment: You want to cahnge the standard browser scrollbar? Possible duplicate: [Change cursor on scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764646/change-cursor-image-on-scrollbar-in-chrome). Would mean it is not possible, sorry :(

Comment: I am afraid that it is impossible in the current implementation because it is rendering as one SVG element.