# Why does the CSS cursor property not work for the styled scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I've styled a **scrollbar**, but **cursor pointer is not working**, even after I put `!important`.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.3vw;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}


/* Handle */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #808080;
  border-radius: 70px;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}


/* Handle on hover */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #424242;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

body {
  height: 90000px;
}
```

I tried and ran it out. I don't see it working.
Can you help me get `cursor: pointer` for `::-WebKit-scrollbar`.
Here are some links for where you can find the scrollbar and cursor pointer:

[1](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

[3](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/)

[4](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp)

[5](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

[6](https://codepen.io/devstreak/pen/dMYgeO)

[7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately due to this [BUG fix of webkit](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=876180), chrome will use the parent's cursor style for the child container.

You can fix your issue by just adding the following CSS:

```
HTML {
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  cursor: default;
  ...
}
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}


/* Handle */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #808080;
  border-radius: 70px;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}


/* Handle on hover */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #424242;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

html {
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  cursor: default;
  height: 90000px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But what if the height of the body is smaller than the html?

Comment: You can have `min-height` on body to `100vh`

Comment: Unfortunately not due to the current limitations due to chrone implementation

Answer (score 0):

My specific use case was - textarea that had cursor as text when hovering my scroll bar. I managed to overcome this issue by using `cursor: inherit` on the text area. Text area still had `cursor: text` as it overrides `default` internally, but scrollbar inherited previous parent's cursor which was `cursor:default`. I would prefer to have `cursor:pointer`, but I don't want to play with body's height or assign text-area's parent `cursor:pointer` or make custom JS-controlled scrollbar.
Pretty niche solution, but might help somebody