# The wrong cursor shows up when I hover over a scrollbar

Tags: html, css

So I'm creating a project where I have a scrollbar next to a textarea element. When I started customizing the scrollbar with ::-webkit-scrollbar, I began to encounter an error.

Whenever I hover over the scroll bar that is next to my textarea element, my mouses' cursor shows up not as the default mouse cursor as it should, but as the text mouse cursor. The main scrollbar at the side of the page is not affected by this.
This is the code that I used to customize the scrollbar:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: var(--color-7);
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
#editor::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-8);
}
```

This is the link to the project on CodePen:
https://codepen.io/Henriksonn/full/GRPpxqr

Comment: I would call this a webkit bug. Not much we can do about it. You can [report a bug](https://bugs.webkit.org).

Comment: Given problem is not reproducible. Please provide supporting screenshots as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64583433/3789527). You can fix your example by setting `cursor: auto` in your `#editor` element.

```
#editor {
    cursor: auto;
}
```